# video compression using silicompressor in android not saving files in android 11

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to compress videos in project therefore using silicompressor. but when I pass it the destination path it create folder correctly but doesn't save file.

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                var videoPath = ""
                try {
                    val file = compressVideosFolderPath
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        file.mkdirs()
                    }
                    videoPath = SiliCompressor.with(applicationContext)
                        .compressVideo(strType, file.path)
                } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "onCreate: ${e.message}",)
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
```

Here is folder path:

```
var compressVideosFolderPath = File(
    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
        .toString() +"/Compress Videos"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get permission of `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in order to write image in `DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` or use MediaStore to create file.